# Conditional Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, bearer-token

I would like to implement Authentication trough JwtBearer and add condition to that bearer with config file key. I have the error when I skip the authentication part: **No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?** that come when I call the API (as json response)

I have some controllers have that decoration:
`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Security.AuthenticationSchemes.Bapi)]`

and here is the code for authentication:

`serviceCollection.AddAuthorization(...).AddAuthentication(...).AddJwtBearer(...)`

This is registered in the startup.cs:
`services.AddBapiAuthorization(Configuration);`

If I do a `if` with the configkey value into the AddAuthorization to apply or not the authorization, I've got the error. How deal with it?

I've already tried to put a "empty" authorization or remove the services.AddBapiAuthorization(Configuration); into startup but it gives me the same error.

Thank you for the help

EDIT:

Add conditional structure

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    if (securityActivated)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddAuthentication()
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    // ...
                });

        serviceCollection.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @clement, You could see steps how to configure Authorization in our lib: https://github.com/Wissance/Authorization

Comment: @MichaelUshakov : thank you but it doesn't respond to my issue when I want to programatically desactivate the authentication

Comment: You could add flag in `appsetting.Json` i.e. `AuthoriztionEnabled`, and at app start you could do something like this: `if(Settings.AuthorizationEnabled) {serviceCollection.AddAuthentication(); //...others}`. If you are trying to check it with runtime probably you could use Middleware that routes requests to Handlers without `Authentication`

Comment: @MichaelUshakov thanks. I've tried to remove the services.AddBapiAuthorization(Configuration); of the startup and let some controller's decorator. Same errorMessage "No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?"

Comment: IMHO only use policy names in `[Authorize]` attributes. Then on startup you can define the policy to allow anonymous access or only jwt tokens.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Authorization` conditionally, you can add `if` condition in `Configure` method instead of `ConfigureServices`.
Which means, you'll add the configuration but the `Authorization`/`Authentication` middleware will run only based on your condition.

Comment: Thanks. When I remove both the [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = ...)] and services.AddBapiAuthorization(Configuration); (in the configureservice or even in the configure section), it's working (no  auth). logical.

Now, when I just add the [Authorize...] and not register (none in service neither configure), error message "No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?" occurs

Comment: You register your Authorization related configuration in ConfigureService and decorate [Authorize] in Controller/Action, this needs to be done in conjunction. Using the middleware in Configure method is the ultimate switch whether Authorization middleware will be triggered on not. You need to put the condition there in the

Comment: Essentially, there are 3 things:
1. Register the middleware in Configure Services method.
2. Decorate the Controller/Action on which Authorization needs to be checked.
3. Use the Middleware by putting it in the Configure Method.

1 and 2 are required in your case, put your condition in the 3rd step.

Comment: amazing, it looks like the solution. Did you have an example or implementation?

Answer (score 0):

**ALWAYS-ON SECURITY**

Instead of disabling security, eg during development, one option for local testing is to call your API with JWT access tokens signed with a test private key, then point your API to a JWKS URI containing the public key.

This enables you to test all of the security and identity related logic productively, with user level access tokens, as in [these example tests](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/test/IntegrationTests.cs#L96) of mine.

**CUSTOM AUTHENTICATION HANDLER**

Sounds like you want the middleware itself to have dynamic behaviour though. A [custom authentication handler](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/host/startup/Startup.cs#L81) can enable that. Maybe look into inheriting from the [JwtBearerHandler class](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs) and overriding the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method based on whether security is currently activated, eg by checking some global state.

**AUTHORIZATION**

If you return `AuthenticateResult.NoResult()` from the handler, an empty ClaimsPrincipal will be created. You would then need to bypass authorization when there is no identity.

**SUMMARY**

Security feature switches are pretty non-standard, add complexity and could be dangerous. Aim to redesign for always-on API security if you can. It will also lead to simpler code.

Comment: We want to enable/disable security with on/off config key without redeploying app

Comment: I prefer an always on model, but see my updated answer on customizing the authentication handler.

Comment: additionally to my answer, extending how JWT or Bapi are doing the authentication may be a solution, still I doubt he got the ideea on how to do it properly, and it will fail later because of default or custom o authorization policies evaluation (403 response instead of 401)

Answer (score 0):

Is impossible, cannot add or remove at runtime per request Authentication or Authorization. AddAuthentication() register all internals as **singletons** at startup, meaning once added to service collection is for eternity. Either middlewares and dependencies are enabled at startup either are not.

If a flag (config, env variable, whatever) controls what and how is enabled (not when, it only one time at startup or when is first time requested), code used it is written incorrectly, it's a if/else problem not rocket science, restarting the app without deployment is the only way to change that if/else initial evaluation.

Secondary, excuse the arrogance, **but here wrong question is asked**, you need to have both (Bearer and Bapi) enabled at same time and **Authorization** middleware determine if proper schema was use based on whatever policy access is required on the resource/endpoint.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bapi")] // this is not conditional, doesn't matter that Bapi authentication scheme was registered or not
```

Solution is to have **Authentication** middleware with a negotiate default scheme for a multi authentication setup, with a policy scheme where the actual negotiation ca be defined inside [options of authentication builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationbuilder.addpolicyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

```
// Set a default NegotiateScheme when multiple authentication schemes are configured 
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "NegotiateScheme";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "NegotiateScheme"; // it can be Bearer for a more restrictive access
        }).AddPolicyScheme("NegotiateScheme", "Authorization with Bearer or Bapi or x-api-key basic", options =>
        {
            options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
            {
                string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
                string basicXApiKeyHeader = context.Request.Headers["x-api-key"].FirstOrDefault();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(basicXApiKeyHeader) == false)
                {
                    return "x-api-key";
                }
                if (authHeader?.StartsWith($"Bearer ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
                {
                    return "Bearer";
                }
                if (authHeader?.StartsWith($"Bapi ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
                {
                    return "Bapi";
                }

                return "Bearer"; // default
            };
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(...)
        .AddJwtBapi(...)
        .AddXApiKey(...);
```

***Disclaimer**: above code is an example, make sure it compile, runs and fits your needs before using.*